# CakePHP - cake bake all error (says missing $default in database.php, but it is present)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to bake all with cake bake all, but it returns all sorts of errors. It says that default in database.php cannot be found, but in reality it is present in the file, also, few days ago I baked few models etc and it worked fine. Here is the output:

```
C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app\Console>cake bake all

Warning Error: Use of undefined constant TESTS - assumed ‘TESTS’ (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in [C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\TaskCollection.php, line 94]
Welcome to CakePHP v2.10.19 Console
App : Console
Path: C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app\Console\
Bake All

Warning Error: include_once(C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app\Console\Config\database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 67]

Warning Error: include_once(): Failed opening ‘C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app\Console\Config\database.php’ for inclusion (include_path=‘C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib;.;C:\php\pear’) in [C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php, line 67]

Error: The datasource configuration “default” was not found in database.php
#0 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Model\ConnectionManager.php(91): ConnectionManager::_getConnectionObject(‘default’)
#1 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(956): ConnectionManager::getDataSource(‘default’)
#2 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(893): ModelTask->getAllTables(‘default’)
#3 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.php(983): ModelTask->listAll(‘default’)
#4 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\Command\BakeShell.php(150): ModelTask->getName(‘default’)
#5 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(459): BakeShell->all()
#6 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(222): Shell->runCommand(‘all’, Array)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#8 C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app\Console\cake.php(47): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#9 {main}
```

Also, here is my database.php file:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'modules',
    'prefix' => '',

// ‘encoding’ => ‘utf8’,
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'test_database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the include errors, they tell you that your `database.php` file cannot be found, and if you look at the path, you see that it looks in the `Console/Config` folder, which is of course the wrong location.

That is because the shell will use the current working directory as the application path, so either run the console from within your `app` folder, ie `Console\cake bake all`, or use the `-app` parameter to pass the path to your `app` folder:

```sh
cake bake all -app "C:\wamp64\www\WarehouseManagementApp\app"
```

The cake shell tells you about that too (`cake --help`), and shows you the relevant paths.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html)**